# Как отсортировать 1 список с помощью 2?

Tags: java, android

Есть 2 списка. Подскажите или дайте совет, как отсортировать 1 список с помощью 2. Архитетктура следующая: 
Listview сортируется через spinner, в котором есть multiple selection. 1 и 2 список типа String

Comment: Можете дать какое то более конкретное объяснение? и желательно с примерами. Уж слишком все расплывчато

Comment: В общем, нужно отфильтровать список всех товаров по параметрам ,выбранными пользователем

Comment: т.е. товары у вас, это список string, и по каким параметрам вы собираетесь сортировать? длинна строки? первая буква?

Comment: В том и задача - нужно отсортировать список товаров по характеристикам. К примеру: список товаров отсортировать по цвету и стране, либо по еще каким-нибудь харктеристикам. При этом пользователь может выбирать одну или несколько характеристик товара одновременно. То есть список фильтруется  по нескольким харктеристикам

Comment: Изучайте ООП. Вам нужен список объектов, со своими характеристиками, вот по ним и сортируйте список